# using c library in another c library, linux

Tags: c, eclipse, static-libraries

Hi All
I wrote a static library (libA) that uses another library (libB).
How can I link libB to my libA in eclipse (linux)? i cannot find linkage options in project properties, they are not on there usual place.
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static libraries don't link. They are an archive of object files (`.o` files). These archives are then taken as arguments during a linking phase, have their object files extracted and linked into the application at that time. As such, static libraries cannot link against anything.